# Merge 2 models (tables) in Django and show it in my template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have 2 models one defines all the all the devices that I have, and the other stores the information that the devices are obtaining. The code of they is the following,

```
class Device(models.Model):
    dev_eui = models.CharField(max_length=16, primary_key=True)
    producer = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    firmware = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    dev_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    fixed = models.BooleanField()
    dev_lat = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    dev_lon = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    deco_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    fleet_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class DevData(models.Model):
    data_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid1, editable=False)
    data_id = models.IntegerField()
    dev_eui = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    gateway = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    data_timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    rssi = models.IntegerField()
    snr = models.IntegerField()
    datarate = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    frequency = models.IntegerField()
    seq = models.IntegerField()
    data_1 = models.FloatField()
    data_2 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    data_3 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    data_4 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    data_5 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    data_6 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    data_7 = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Actually what I want is show a table in my template, combining all the data from `devData` and adding the `dev_name` and `fleet_id` from `devices`.

Now what I'm doing is obtaining all the data and in the template filtering it. But I'm sure it's better and easier doing this in the `views.py`, but I don't know how.

Reading some info, I found the `union()` function but it's not working and I'm not sure if is the best option,

```
@login_required(login_url='/user_app/login/')
def user_data(request):
    dev_data = DevData.objects.all()
    devices = Device.objects.all()

    test = DevData.objects.all().values_list(
        "dev_eui"
    ).union(
    Device.objects.all().values_list(
        "dev_eui"
    ))

    ctx = {'DevData':dev_data,'Devices':devices, 'Test':test}
    return render(request, template_name='data.html', context=ctx)
```

This join shows nothing.

Can somebody help me? Thank very much!

Answer (score 1):

You need a foreign key relating the two models.

```
class Device(models.Model):
    dev_eui = models.CharField(max_length=16, primary_key=True)

class DevData(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKeyField(Device, related_name='dev_data', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data_uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid1, editable=False)
    data_id = models.IntegerField()
    # This is not needed, it can be accessed via instance.device.dev_eui now
    # dev_eui = models.CharField(max_length=16)
```

Then to get all of the DevData instances for a particular device:

```
for device in Device.objects.all():
    x = device.dev_data.all()
```

Please read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related) to better understand relationship fields.

Comment: Thank you very much, one last question, you say I can remove the line of dev_eui. Is this possible because this foreign key is now dev_eui?

Comment: No. The foreign key field gives you access to the Device model which has the `dev_eui` field directly on it.